# Как сделать так чтобы react перерендерил разметку по условию?

Tags: reactjs

У меня есть родительский компонент, в нем я принимаю пропсами язык, в зависимости от языка я должен рендерить разметку.
В скрипте я подключаю jivo chat.
После смены языка в данный момент у меня виджет не меняется на другой язык, но если я перезагружу страницу то подгружается уже язык какой мне нужен.
Как мне добиться поведения когда при смене языка у меня менялся бы виджет?

Компонент с виджетом:

```
type Props = {
    lang?: string | null;
};

export const Jivo = (props: Props) => {
    const { lang } = props;

    return (
        <>
            {lang === 'ru' ? (
                <script src='//code.jivo.ru/widget/v0tzhy0uhW' async></script>
            ) : (
                <script src='//code.jivo.ru/widget/sIH7pKEUXN' async></script>
            )}
        </>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Создать для компонента состояние и повесить useEffect, который будет срабатывать при изменении props.lang и сохранять данные в состояние компонента.

При изменении состояния, произойдет ререндер

```
export const Jivo = (props: Props) => {
    const [lang, setLang] = useState(props.lang);

    useEffect(() => {
        setLang(lang);
    }, [props.lang]);

    return (
        <>
            {lang === 'ru' ? (
                <script src='//code.jivo.ru/widget/v0tzhy0uhW' async></script>
            ) : (
                <script src='//code.jivo.ru/widget/sIH7pKEUXN' async></script>
            )}
        </>
    );
};
```

Comment: Насколько я знаю когда в компонент приходят новые пропсы то он и так рендерится, в данном случае ваш способ не сработал. Всем так же остается виджет который зарендерился при первом рендере

Comment: @yOz Впихните туда console.log() и посмотрие, он вообще дергается? И не может ли быть такого, что компонент отрабатывает верно, но вот второй скрипт не может перезатереть первый?

Comment: Вот и я не пойму в чем дело. Пропсы приходят, лог выводит смену языка. Я даже пробовал получить до него доступ по id и потом удалить из дом елемента по условию - так же не сработало. Хочу понять в чем может быть проблема.. По какой-то причине он не хочет делать условие пока я не перезагружу страницу - очень странно, мне кажется, что я что-то упускаю..

Comment: Я не знаю, поможет или нет... Ну как на попробовать. Добавьте этим `<script>` id или data-id что бы можно было найти в DOM. В момент смены попробуйте принудительно удалить из DOM старый скрипт, а уже потом добавить новый. Я просто не знаю, что делают эти скрипты у вас на сайте и как из них вы данные тянете. Возможно имеет смысл попробовать что то принудительно перинициализировать...

Comment: `setLang(lang);` - тут случайно не опечатка? Нужно же `setLang(props.lang);`